# How fast can a flood realistically occur (perhaps factoring in climate change)?

Tags: internal-consistency, climate, weather

This is sort of on the more realistic side of worldbuilding, but maybe somewhat exaggerated for the sake of a setting.  What's the fastest atmospheric pressure drop in weather records?  This question is kind of more asking how quickly a flash flood could happen, especially maybe a decade in a future.  Of course, heavy rainfall contributes to that, but a storm surge caused by wind and pressure is what I'm interested in.

Comment: Define flood.  My street can flood in 30 minutes of hard rain.

Comment: In a flash. Can you define the geography and weather conditions you're talking about?

Comment: A surge because of a strong storm or a limited strength hurricane, and for an area that's at sea level.

Comment: You ask about atmospheric pressure, but flash floods often occur far outside the area where the rain actually fell. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORZQUlk8vxg

Comment: Practical example: Northern California last Sunday.  Get a heavy warm rain on top of a good mountain snowpack, and it doesn't take long at all.

Comment: watch a flash flood in action. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81LKbgHjQ_0

Answer (score 3):

**Global warming ==> big hurricane with storm surge ==> landfall into a funnel-shaped bay ==> huge wave/flood up the bay!**

FYI, the sharpest barometric pressure drops are (I'm pretty sure) inside tornados -- but those are too short-lived and move too erratically to cause the sort of flooding you're seeking.

Instead, consider the phenomena knowns as Tidal Bores:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_bore
 which tells us that the largest one on earth is:

> Qiantang River, China, which has the world's largest bore, up to 9
>   meters (30 ft) high, traveling at up to 40 kilometers (25 mi) per hour

So this gives you both a ballpark flood height and a speed.
It's apparently popular for extreme surfing (video; I couldn't make this up): 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvO5Ckd7mlU

Now, imagine the storm surge from a big (possibly global warming enchanced) hurricane, making landfall into a bay/river prone to tidal bores.  Head for high ground.

Answer (score 1):

My creek flooded in 10 minutes. One moment I was standing on the bank, the next I was watching my dumpster float away, after that, I was carrying my baby brother and my precious belongings up the hill because we could not get out of the valley. So flash floods can happen fast.

Comment: Thank you for the answers guys.  Just a part of an action scene I was imagining.  I might end up using a flood not caused by weather, but I'm not sure, so I appreciate the answers to this somewhat vague question.